# EJB3 on Weblogic 10 - Timeout on first DB access

Tags: java, timeout, ejb-3.0, eclipselink, weblogic-10.x

I have an EJB3 application which I deploy on various environments, namely Weblogic 10 for Windows with Apache webserver and Weblogic 10 for Linux with IIS webserver. I'm using EclipseLink as a persistence layer. The DB is always Oracle 9.2 on Windows machines.

My persistence.xml connects me (where "me" is the session beans) to one or more Oracle Datasources. There are 3 session beans used to access 3 data sources, one each.

On Windows!Weblogic, which is the development environment, there are no problems, but when I deploy on Linux machines (testing & production environment), all session beans give a timeout exception once or twice on first database access, then work perfectly fine. Any configuration, as per Weblogic console, is the same, plus I don't have write access to settings on production environments, so I also must keep development & testing aligned. **So no configuration settings on Weblogic console (such as increasing transaction timeout) will do.**

Any idea on what am I missing here? Thanks!

**Edit**: Here is a sample exception stack trace. It is invariably the same every time.

```
2012-01-11 14:31:35,548 ERROR [org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/wls001/beasys/wls10/config/dwcrete/servers/i1wcrete2/tmp/_WL_user/maretcEAR/u5f4ij/dataProvider-3.0.jar_MaretcSecurityDS] internalLog 648 - Jan 11, 2012 2:31:34 PM org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/wls001/beasys/wls10/config/dwcrete/servers/i1wcrete2/tmp/_WL_user/maretcEAR/u5f4ij/dataProvider-3.0.jar_MaretcSecurityDS ServerSession(39783972) Thread(34)
SEVERE: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction BEA1-47235794E4F50336CEC4 not active anymore. tx status = Rolled back. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 31 seconds 
BEA1-47235794E4F50336CEC4]
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connect(DatasourceAccessor.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.buildConnection(ConnectionPool.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ExternalConnectionPool.startUp(ExternalConnectionPool.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.connect(ServerSession.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at weblogic.deployment.EntityManagerFactoryProxyImpl.invoke(EntityManagerFactoryProxyImpl.java:77)
    at $Proxy435.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.deployment.TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.newPersistenceContext(TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.java:74)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.getPersistenceContext(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:147)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:88)
    at weblogic.deployment.TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.invoke(TransactionalEntityManagerProxyImpl.java:90)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.invoke(BasePersistenceContextProxyImpl.java:80)
    at $Proxy436.getDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at it.enel.base.ejb.DataProvider.execute(DataProvider.java:55)
    at it.enel.base.ejb.DataProvider.execute(DataProvider.java:42)
    at it.enel.base.ejb.DataProvider.createAndExecuteCheck(DataProvider.java:162)
    at it.enel.base.ejb.DataProvider.checkDomain(DataProvider.java:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:281)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:187)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:154)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:114)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:114)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
    at $Proxy446.checkDomain(Unknown Source)
    at it.enel.base.ejb.DataProviderEJB_bfyhct_DataProviderRemoteImpl.checkDomain(DataProviderEJB_bfyhct_DataProviderRemoteImpl.java:145)
    at it.enel.base.ejb.DataProviderEJB_bfyhct_DataProviderRemoteImpl_CBV.checkDomain(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:63)
    at $Proxy437.checkDomain(Unknown Source)
    at it.enel.maretc.business.transfer.SecurityModel.checkDomain(SecurityModel.java:71)
    at it.enel.maretc.struts2.business.model.user.User.isDomainValid(User.java:102)
    at it.enel.maretc.struts2.action.login.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3393)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2140)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2046)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction BEA1-47235794E4F50336CEC4 not active anymore. tx status = Rolled back. [Reason=weblogic.transaction.internal.TimedOutException: Transaction timed out after 31 seconds 
BEA1-47235794E4F50336CEC4]
    at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.getTransaction(Driver.java:540)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.connect(Driver.java:109)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:126)
    ... 112 more
```

Comment: where is the exception stack trace?

Comment: The problem may be that on first connections, the WLS tries to acquire a connection while the transaction is already active and thus, it times out. Could this be?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think why there would be a difference on the two machines, but it needs to be looked into.  A workaround could be to use the  eclipselink.deploy-on-startup flag with a value of true, which would cause some of the EclipseLink initialization to be done upfront instead of at first access.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to speed up the first connection, did not solve the problem though.